# Making batch file for copying

Tags: command-line, copy, dos, xcopy

Can anyone advise me please im using Windows XP Pro on C drive and need to be able to copy a file from one drive to another. This case original will have to be renamed  and old file must be put on another Partiton which is on a Server Example K drive. 
Alternately There is another option using Windows 7 on a another computer instead of Windows XP Pro. So any answers appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look on my old DOS book that I saved just in case that I have to make batch files says COPY is the right command.
Syntax:

> COPY DRIVE:FILENAME DRIVE:FILENAME
>   COPY THISFILE THATFILE

Comment: Thanks for that I was trying get more info on switches. Basically knew about that but just getting all the correct things in correct places.

Comment: what switches are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If your permissions are setup to allow copying, you can use "[UNC](http://www.uwplatt.edu/oit/terms/uncpath.html)" paths to copy files across servers and drives.

Like Noah said, check out [ROBOCOPY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) or the slightly less featured [XCOPY](http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Enter `copy /?` or `xcopy /?` to find out the available options - if you append `>file.txt` you'll get them in a text file.

Comment: woot I never knew that :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

XCOPY Command:

```
xcopy c:\sourceDirectory\*.* d:\destinationDirectory\*.* /D /E /C /R /Y
```

ROBOCOPY Command:

```
robocopy c:\sourceDirectory\*.* d:\destinationDirectory\*.* /R:5 /W:3 /Z /XX /TEE
```

Either of these should work for you

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into robocopy?

Comment: yes had a look at that but just doing it for a test and not allowed to use Robocopy. Thanks for reply

Comment: For a 'test'? I don't understand.